# Is "cover up the original record" correct?

Tags: word-choice

I want to express that I need to use a new record to replace the original one. For example, after we have re-edited the writing, we might want to save it so that it could replace the original draft. I am wondering if the following expression is correct in a formal letter.

> I would like to cover up my old record with the updated one.

Because cover up might seen with the meaning of covering something not good purposefully.

Comment: Yes, it sounds shifty.

Comment: Thx Dear @Lawrence. So what do you suggest I should use here?

Comment: Consider *replace*.

Comment: What's wrong with simply saying *replace*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the term 'overwrite'. That's the normal term used in computing for replacing an old record with the new one. The old record is 'overwritten' by the new one - so it no longer exists, in its old form - the new one has erased it and taken its place.

Comment: Good. That’s what I want. Thx Jelila

Comment: Great! @exteralvictor 